# Python: ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)

Tags: python

This is my code.Line 21 raises the warning.I don't know why it appear.I have search for a long time,but i still can't get the answer.

```
from scipy import fftpack
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.fftpack as sci_fft
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVC
dataframe = pd.read_csv('D:\\Lab\\data_aft\\xadata.csv',header=None)
trans = dataframe.values
lab_data_fft = np.array(fftpack.fft(trans[:,0:-1],n = 8),
                    dtype=complex)
target = trans[:,-1]
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(lab_data_fft,target,
                                                  test_size=0.333,
                                                 random_state=1)
clf = SVC(kernel='rbf',
      gamma=1,
      C=10,
      decision_function_shape='ovr')
clf.fit(x_train,y_train)
pred = clf.predict(x_test)
score = clf.score(x_test,y_test)
```

Btw,i'm new to python :).Thanks!

Comment: Which line raises the warning?

Comment: Line 21 raises the warning